# ui-grid row to have unique id's

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is it possible to have each row in the ui-grid have a unique id?  Something along the lines of the first row having an id of "row-0" and the second having "row-1" etc

So:

```
<div class="ui-grid-row" 
    ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected,'ui-grid-tree-header-row': row.treeLevel > -1}" 
    ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" 
    ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)">
        ...
</div>
```

Would look something like:

```
<div class="ui-grid-row" 
    id="row-0"
    ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected,'ui-grid-tree-header-row': row.treeLevel > -1}" 
    ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" 
    ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)">
        ...
</div>
```

I have tried the row template but that is setting the id on each cell (probably as expected)

It is so that whilst using Selenium I can select a row by finding it using the id

**UPDATE:** I have now tried setting the Id on the row template to

```
row-{{rowRenderIndex}}-cell-{{col.uid}}
```

and this generates something along the lines of

```
id="row-0-cell-uiGrid-0007"
```

if I then navigate away from the screen and come back again the id becomes

```
id="row-0-cell-uiGrid-00PW"
```

If the id was consistent each time then I could use this

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. However, if you have more then one table those ids will not be unique. Would it be better to set the unique id on the table container, and have selenium select row by css nth-child?

Comment: The grid has an id but I was hoping to have each row have it's own id, just to make it easier to find the rows

Comment: But to answer your question ... gridOptions does have a "rowTemplate" property, so you could use that.

Comment: As I said I've tried the row template.  I am sure it is possible to add an id to each row but for some reason I just cannot figure it out.  On each cell isn't a problem, that I can do

Comment: I have added further information to the original question regarding what I have tried

Comment: I have the same issue. col.uid changes after navigation. Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Juri I don't think I found a solution sorry, I'm not working on that project anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can use $index

```
<div class="ui-grid-row" 
    id="{{$index}}"
    ng-class="{'ui-grid-row-selected': row.isSelected,'ui-grid-tree-header-row': row.treeLevel > -1}" 
    ng-repeat="(rowRenderIndex, row) in rowContainer.renderedRows track by $index" 
    ng-style="Viewport.rowStyle(rowRenderIndex)">
        ...
</div>
```

Comment: as I said I have tried that and each cell ends up with the id's as "row-0"; "row-1" etc, each row having cells with the same id's

Comment: This is because ui-grid-row uses ui-grid-cell. 
Try using "ui-grid-one-bind-id-grid" 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid/blob/master/src/templates/ui-grid/ui-grid-row.html

Comment: That appears to be on each cell again and not the actual row

Answer (score 0):

The row and column together forms a tuple (row,column) which is unique for every cell in the grid. For UI-Grid, there is a way to use this concept.
Each cell has access to internal scope variable of UI-grid. In this scope there are two keys 'row' and 'col'. Each of these has uid property.
Therefore, use the tuple ('row.uid','col.uid') is always unique for each cell. 
Example of usage (Angular JS):

```
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" trigger-id="{{row.uid + col.uid}}">
{{ COL_FIELD }}</div>
```

Trigger id is unique for each cell. For multiple grids on same page pass name the grid in scope variable and access it using `grid.appScope.gridName`